# Create a variable in python with the values from each row of a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I want to use the following code in order to translate text from specific columns of my df and export it into the same df. The code works excepting for the case when the column value is blank/empty. Also, the values for my SourceLanguageCode and TargetLanguageCode are found on each row of the columns 'source' and 'target' in my df, since they are different for each row so it is possible to read them from there and not provide the language in the parameters?

```
cols_to_translate = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
 for col in cols_to_translate:
    df[f'translated_{col}'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: translate.translate_text(Text=x,
       SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr').get('TranslatedText')
```

[image]

It should result something like this

```
cols_to_translate = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
for col in cols_to_translate:
  df[f'translated_{col}'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: translate.translate_text(Text=x,
    SourceLanguageCode=sc, TargetLanguageCode=tg).get('TranslatedText')
```

Where tg should be equivalent of each row for column 'target' and sc equivalent for rows on 'source' column when translating on rows but I don't know how to express this in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def translate(row, text_col):
    return translate.translate_text(
            Text=row[col],
            SourceLanguageCode=row.source, 
            TargetLanguageCode=row.target).get('TranslatedText')



cols_to_translate = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
for col in cols_to_translate:
    df[f'translated_{col}'] = df.apply(lambda row: translate(row, col), axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you but returns this error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'translate_text'

Comment: Please always when posting a code add a description how that code works and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @ruslantau, thank you so much for taking your time, it is working at a first glance, will double check and mark the answer as the correct one if all good. Again, thanks a ton!!